# Posting non-editable values in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using jqgrid 3.8.2 and the grid have many columns that are non-editable but still want to be posted to the server. How I can do that? (If I set editable:false then the field is not getting posted the the server)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to me that the column settings

```
hidden: true, editable: true, editrules: { edithidden: false }
```

will do what you need.

Comment: but the columns are not hidden in the grid. ex. for such a column is CreatedDate the user can't edit that but still has to be posted to the server.

Comment: @Vijaya Anand: You don't post any code, so the communication can be longer. jqGrid supports three standard editing mode: inline editing, form editing and cell editing. The answer on your question depend on which mode you use.

Comment: @Vijaya Anand: If you have at interest to solve the problem you should post the JavaScript code which you use.

Comment: @Oleg An attribute like editnochange should be added to specify to pass a value as a uneditable field but still send it to the server. THis would avoid the little hack as in Tom's answer

Comment: @singe3: I agree with you. I introduced already `editable: "hidden"`, `editable: "disabled"` and  `editable: `"readonly" in [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) - the fork of jqGrid, which I develop. See [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/editable-property-of-colModel-as-function). I see now that the option `editable: "hidden"` should be implemented in **inline editing** too. Currently it's work only for form editing. I will write you one more comment after I will make the changed in free jqGrid.

Comment: @singe3: I have published [the changes](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/commit/ef12551895642ab6ea0368f571626f0d4098dbcc) to GitHub just now. Thus one can use `editable: "hidden"` for any column to send the data to the server *without* making the column editable or hidden. If you now yet use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) then you can try it by changing URLs to the values described in [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs#access-githib-code-from-rawgit). Thanks you one more for your suggestion.

Answer (score 7):

I realize this question is pretty old now but I needed to do this same thing today and the accepted answer doesn't actually answer the question. Sorry Oleg, you are still awesome. Anyway, if you have visible columns and are doing inline editing where some of those columns should not be editable the following worked for me.

Use these column setting

```
editable: true, edittype: 'custom', editoptions: { custom_element: readOnlyElement, custom_value: readOnlyValue}
```

and define these functions

```
function readOnlyElement(value, options) {
    return $('<span></span>', { text: value });
},

function readOnlyValue(elem, operation, value) {
    if (operation === 'get') {
        return $(elem).text();
    } else if (operation === 'set') {
        $('span', elem).text(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've lost 2 hours looking for a clean way to do that ! Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

About 'editable: "hidden"'...
This method is perfect until you change the contents of a cell. With 'editable:' hidden '', the jqgrid does not contain **`<input />`** but **`aria-describedby`** which is less simple to target.
ex:

without 'editable:"hidden"'
you target the input by its 'id '==>' `$("#yourgrid #jqg3_your_field")`

with 'editable:' hidden 'you target like that ...
You need your current row id

```
rowID = $("#yourgrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');

$("tr[id='"+rowID+"'] [aria-describedby='yourgrid_your_field']>.u-jqgrid-cell-wrapper").html()
```

It's a lot less convenient :-)
Despite everything, it works very well ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I see the answer in the comments for Oleg's answer by @singe3. 
Set,

```
editable: "hidden"
```